# Reading NFC card using a button(Isodep)

Tags: android, nfc, contactless-smartcard

I am quite new to android development and trying to read an nfc card and was wondering if it's possible to read it when the user presses a button. I know how to read a card once the card is near the reader or when it is tapped to the nfc reader (onTagDiscovered). I would like to know if it's possible when a user presses a button then the device will read the card.

Comment: do you mean physical device button , or a button in software UI ?

Comment: what I mean is a software UI

Answer (score 0):

Android not working as this.

1. You could declare in your `AndroidManifest` that an `Activity` in your application could read NFC tag.

When a tag is detected by system,

- if only your application declared that could reading NFC tags then your `Activity` is launched with discovered tag in `Intent`
- if multiple application declared that could reading NFC tags 
  then a "popup" is shown to user to choose application

The other solution

2. You use `enableForgroundDispatch` : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch

> The foreground dispatch system allows an activity to intercept an
>   intent and claim priority over other activities that handle the same
>   intent. Using this system involves constructing a few data structures
>   for the Android system to be able to send the appropriate intents to
>   your application. To enable the foreground dispatch system

If multiple applications "listen" to NFC tag and your `Activity` is in foreground and `enableForgroundDispatch` then only your application, receive NFC discovered Tag .

With previous mechanism, you could catch all tags in your `Activity` and when user press a button do required action, when user not press button, do nothing.